# Detected Hardware Unit Hang with 82566DC / e1001e

Tags: 14.04, ethernet, e1000

I am suddenly having problems with a Ubuntu Server install. This machine ran fine with 12.04, 13.10 and also for a while with 14.04.

It started doing this:

```
12:44:34  e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Detected Hardware Unit Hang:
12:44:34    TDH                  <75>
12:44:34    TDT                  <77>
12:44:34    next_to_use          <77>
12:44:34    next_to_clean        <75>
12:44:34  buffer_info[next_to_clean]:
12:44:34    time_stamp           <100e01775>
12:44:34    next_to_watch        <75>
12:44:34    jiffies              <100e01ed3>
12:44:34    next_to_watch.status <0>
12:44:34  MAC Status             <802a3>
12:44:34  PHY Status             <792d>
12:44:34  PHY 1000BASE-T Status  <3800>
12:44:34  PHY Extended Status    <3000>
12:44:34  PCI Status             <10>
12:44:34  e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
12:44:37  e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
12:45:59  e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
```

After that, the interface sometimes comes back, mostly don't.

I have not ruled out broken hardware yet, but I would be surprised if that were the case.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that worked for me, as described [here](https://serverfault.com/q/616485).

You can try the following command:

```
ethtool -K eth0 gso off gro off tso off
```

Let me know if it works for you.

**Edit:** It seems that this solution only helped a little bit with the problem. I got the same error later when the NIC got a heavy load. It seems like a hardware problem. I've swapped the NIC  and until now I didn't see this error. Perhaps you should try to test on another network card and see if it solves the problem.