# igb Detected Tx Unit Hang

Tags: 14.04, networking, kernel

Have a:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty
```

with kenel 3.16.0-46-generic.

Today i do dist-upgrade and kernel was upgraded to 3.16.0-48-generic version.

After reboot i've got this:

```
Sep 4 09:02:52 mail kernel: [ 310.616324] igb 0000:02:00.0 em1: Reset adapter
Sep 4 09:02:52 mail kernel: [ 310.831157] igb 0000:02:00.1 em2: Reset adapter 
Sep 4 09:02:56 mail kernel: [ 315.154686] igb 0000:02:00.0 em1: igb: em1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX 
Sep 4 09:02:56 mail kernel: [ 315.202651] igb 0000:02:00.1 em2: igb: em2 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX 
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] igb 0000:02:00.0: Detected Tx Unit Hang
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] Tx Queue <6>
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] TDH <23>
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] TDT <23>
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] next_to_use <25>
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] next_to_clean <23>
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] buffer_info[next_to_clean]
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] time_stamp <1000012af>
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] next_to_watch <ffff880272571240>
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] jiffies <100001531>
Sep 4 09:03:02 mail kernel: [ 321.608099] desc.status <120200>
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] igb 0000:02:00.0: Detected Tx Unit Hang
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] Tx Queue <6>
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] TDH <23>
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] TDT <23>
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] next_to_use <25>
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] next_to_clean <23>
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] buffer_info[next_to_clean]
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] time_stamp <1000012af>
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] next_to_watch <ffff880272571240>
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] jiffies <100001725>
Sep 4 09:03:04 mail kernel: [ 323.607349] desc.status <120200>
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] igb 0000:02:00.0: Detected Tx Unit Hang
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] Tx Queue <6>
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] TDH <23>
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] TDT <23>
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] next_to_use <25>
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] next_to_clean <23>
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] buffer_info[next_to_clean]
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] time_stamp <1000012af>
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] next_to_watch <ffff880272571240>
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] jiffies <100001919>
Sep 4 09:03:06 mail kernel: [ 325.606602] desc.status <120200>
```

All network connections droped after that. System still unusable.

Only after boot with old linux-image-3.16.0-46-generic my production mail server can work.

It's a critical bug for me, can anybody help me?

```
ethtool -i em1
driver: igb
version: 5.2.13-k
firmware-version: 1.61, 0x80000cd5, 1.949.0
bus-info: 0000:02:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Comment: I confirm having the same problem. The system works after returning to older kernel. It happened after today's auto-update. My motherboard with the NICs is X9DRD-7JLN4F.

Comment: I created bug report for this case at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1492146 and there is no answer yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to switch to a new vivid kernel, which is default in the case of a clean installation for Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-signed-generic-lts-vivid
```

in my case, cause have UEFI BIOS and

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

in case of legacy BIOS.

Utopic kernels can be removed.

Comment: This seems to be working for me too

Comment: Update: One of my servers hangs shortly after the network becomes available :( This seems to work for the majority of them however.

Comment: Even with new vivid kernel? I have 5 equal HP Proliant DL120 G9 servers. All of them use vivid kernel with any problems.

Comment: It locks up with the new kernel one second after network becomes available

Comment: May be better for you to revert to any old working kernel in this case.

Comment: Booted " 3.13.0-63-generic" which is working... for now. Nervous running a kernel that old. We'll probably archive all the VMs and wipe the box. Machines with same hardware are running the Vivid kernel just fine, so it's likely just something on this particular installation.

Comment: You can track my bug report on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1492146 about this case.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here after upgrading to 3.16.0-48.

We are using Intel S2600GZ4 Servers with 4x Intel I350 Gigabit Ethernet.
We had to force Grub to boot 3.16.0-46 to solve the problem.

```
[ 3187.380957] igb 0000:02:00.0 em1: Reset adapter
[ 3187.403245] igb 0000:02:00.2 em3: Reset adapter
[ 3187.403257] igb 0000:02:00.1 em2: Reset adapter
[ 3187.403259] igb 0000:02:00.3 em4: Reset adapter
[ 3188.858759] igb 0000:02:00.0 em1: igb: em1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[ 3190.295762] igb 0000:02:00.2 em3: igb: em3 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[ 3190.754805] igb 0000:02:00.2 em3: igb: em3 NIC Link is Down
[ 3191.208233] igb 0000:02:00.3 em4: igb: em4 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[ 3191.728507] igb 0000:02:00.1 em2: igb: em2 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[ 3194.365870] igb 0000:02:00.2 em3: igb: em3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[ 3195.445233] igb 0000:02:00.3 em4: igb: em4 NIC Link is Down
[ 3196.189620] igb 0000:02:00.2 em3: igb: em3 NIC Link is Down
[ 3198.435979] igb 0000:02:00.3 em4: igb: em4 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[ 3199.641563] igb 0000:02:00.2 em3: igb: em3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[ 3207.043242] igb 0000:02:00.3 em4: igb: em4 NIC Link is Down
[ 3209.384430] igb 0000:02:00.0: Detected Tx Unit Hang
[ 3209.384430]   Tx Queue             <2>
[ 3209.384430]   TDH                  <0>
[ 3209.384430]   TDT                  <0>
[ 3209.384430]   next_to_use          <2>
[ 3209.384430]   next_to_clean        <0>
[ 3209.384430] buffer_info[next_to_clean]
[ 3209.384430]   time_stamp           <1000b1520>
[ 3209.384430]   next_to_watch        <ffff880fe2f68010>
[ 3209.384430]   jiffies              <1000b177e>
[ 3209.384430]   desc.status          <528200>
[ 3210.514216] igb 0000:02:00.3 em4: igb: em4 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[ 3211.385464] igb 0000:02:00.0: Detected Tx Unit Hang
[ 3211.385464]   Tx Queue             <2>
[ 3211.385464]   TDH                  <0>
[ 3211.385464]   TDT                  <0>
[ 3211.385464]   next_to_use          <2>
[ 3211.385464]   next_to_clean        <0>
[ 3211.385464] buffer_info[next_to_clean]
[ 3211.385464]   time_stamp           <1000b1520>
[ 3211.385464]   next_to_watch        <ffff880fe2f68010>
[ 3211.385464]   jiffies              <1000b1972>
[ 3211.385464]   desc.status          <528200>
[ 3213.386510] igb 0000:02:00.0: Detected Tx Unit Hang
[ 3213.386510]   Tx Queue             <2>
[ 3213.386510]   TDH                  <0>
[ 3213.386510]   TDT                  <0>
[ 3213.386510]   next_to_use          <2>
[ 3213.386510]   next_to_clean        <0>
[ 3213.386510] buffer_info[next_to_clean]
[ 3213.386510]   time_stamp           <1000b1520>
[ 3213.386510]   next_to_watch        <ffff880fe2f68010>
[ 3213.386510]   jiffies              <1000b1b66>
[ 3213.386510]   desc.status          <528200>
[ 3214.386947] igb 0000:02:00.0 em1: Reset adapter
[ 3214.409233] igb 0000:02:00.2 em3: Reset adapter
[ 3214.409236] igb 0000:02:00.1 em2: Reset adapter
[ 3214.409237] igb 0000:02:00.3 em4: Reset adapter
[ 3215.844779] igb 0000:02:00.0 em1: igb: em1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[ 3217.918078] igb 0000:02:00.1 em2: igb: em2 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[ 3218.255206] igb 0000:02:00.2 em3: igb: em3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[ 3218.366303] igb 0000:02:00.3 em4: igb: em4 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my experience to this thread to make it more complete.

My experience is the same that network adapter became virtually not usable after upgrading to kernel 3.16.0-48. I couldn't even complete an `apt-get update`.

I followed [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460160/detected-hardware-unit-hang-with-82566dc-e1001e) to run the command `ethtool -K eth0 gso off gro off tso off`. Then I successfully completed an `apt-get upgrade` to upgrade the linux ternel to 3.16.0-49. The problem was gone after a reboot. I'm not sure if the `ethtool -K eth0 gso off gro off tso off` command helped at this point.

My takeaway was that you can still run a `apt-get upgrade` even if you didn't complete a `apt-get update`.